# Trying to improve a query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to get the amount of operations from a company in two different currencies (dollars and bolivianos). I made two queries in a stored procedure and it works. My problem is that I do not know how to merge them in a unique query because they are almost the same.

```
SELECT @amount_dollars = ISNULL(SUM(Amount), 0.00) 
FROM ProcessBatches
WHERE 
    CompanyId = @company_id
    AND CONVERT(CHAR(8), DateProcess, 112) = @current_date
    AND Currency = 'USD'
    AND OperationTypeId NOT IN (17,18)
    AND State IN ('P','W','N','A')

SELECT @amount_bols = ISNULL(SUM(Amount), 0.00)
FROM ProcessBatches
WHERE 
    CompanyId = @company_id
    AND CONVERT(CHAR(8), DateProcess, 112) = @current_date
    AND Currency = 'BOL'
    AND OperationTypeId NOT IN (17,18)
    AND State IN ('P','W','N','A')
```

I am not an expert in SQL. Thanks in advance and sorry for my english (I am learning)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT @amount_dollars = COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN Currency = 'USD' THEN Amount END), 0.00) ,
       @amount_bols = COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN Currency = 'BOL' THEN Amount END), 0.00)          
FROM ProcessBatches
WHERE  CompanyId = @company_id AND
       CAST(DateProcess as date) = @current_date AND
       Currency IN ('BOL', 'USD') AND
       OperationTypeId NOT IN (17, 18) AND
       State IN ('P', 'W', 'N', 'A');
```

Note:  I changed the `date` comparison to use the `date` data type.  This is much better than using string comparisons.  Plus, the conversion to date still allows the use of indexes (in SQL Server).

Comment: Yeah!, it works. Thanks. I don't know the COALESCE function.

Comment: @Héctor Álvarez: "please avoid putting indexes on date types". Why?

Comment: @HéctorÁlvarez If I could downvote your comments I would. Indexing date columns is a very common and effective strategy. There is a cost to any index, regardless of datatype; you balance the cost with the benefit. In addition, it is typical that any set of columns in an index will not be unique. You create an index on customerid for a transaction table. That will certainly not be unique - how does that cause errors?

Comment: @HéctorÁlvarez . . . A date column does not "increase the index size exponentially".  As with any other type, each value adds a bit more than 1 record to the index (to account for the B-tree shape).  Dates are no worse or better than other types.  And there is definitely no requirement that the keys of an index be unique -- otherwise most of the world's indexes would be invalid.